# Standard Numeric Input With if else command in c

Tags: c

how to strict the user to just enter a number when the programme ask about the input or just how to apply numeric input on a entry can anyone help me out.

as a exmpale:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
  void main()
     {
        int x;
        printf("Enter a numeric value:");
        scanf("%d",&x);

        if(..........)    // here i supose to write the if statement  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` returns the number of parameters successfully processed, so you need to store its return value and test that.

Therefore, you can do `if (scanf("%d", &x)) { ... } else {... }` instead, since `scanf` will either return 0 (no integer was matched) or 1 (if an integer was matched)

**EDIT**

```
if (scanf("%d", &x)) {
    /* an integer was read into x, so what do you want to do here? */
} else {
    /* what the user typed was not an integer, so normally you want to write some error message or something */
}
```

Comment: can u plz written the whole statement i did not understant what to write in if {body} or else {body}

Comment: scanf("%d",...) has no over/underflow range check, try an input like "999999999999999999999999999999999999999", scanf gives OK but isn't

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the whole line which inputed by user, then use isdigit()(defined in ctype.h) to check each charactor to see if it is a number.

Comment: but i can't use isdigit or ctype.h i don't know about this function or header file

Comment: This is unnecessarily slow and painful. Many implementations have an actual nontrivial function for `isdigit` despite the C standard requiring it to return nonzero if and only if `((unsigned)c-'0'<10)`.

Comment: @R If the function is trivial it's probably inlined by the compiler. There's no point in premature optimization. Also, even if that "conversion" works, it's cryptical. There's a reason why the function "isdigit()" exists.

Comment: isdigit fails on heading sign in inputstream, like +3 or -3

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to check here:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1024751&page=10

Interestingly enough, that is also the first result on Google.

Also, stop using void main(). It's restricting.

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider taking input in a infinite while loop, and break out of it when the user enters the proper input.

Answer (score 0):

- void main isn' t ANSI C
- conio.h isn't ANSI C
- e.g. look at
  [do-while loop for checking users input using c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172370/do-while-loop-for-checking-users-input-using-c/4172680#4172680)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user's input to satisfy a certain condition, you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter a numeric value:");

    scanf("%d", &x);

    //suppose you want the user to enter values b/w 0 and 999
    while ((x < 0) || (x >= 1000)) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }
}
```

Remember, `void main` and `conio.h` are not standard compliant.